Display Recordset based on Data field Value in SSRS
I have a problem to display recordset based on Data Field Value. For example, here I have two tables that is Master Item and Master Transaction:
Master Item
|ItemId| |Name     |  |Capacity|
|12345 | |Miki Hat |  | 5      |
|54321 | |Jacket   |  | 5     |

Master Transaction
Order number    ItemId itemSerial   Name            Qty
Onum012     12345  12345a       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345b       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345c       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345d       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345e       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345f       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345g       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345h       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345i       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345j       Miki Hat            1

Onum013     54321  54321       Jacket       1

I want to create report for order transaction queue, to display recordset based on Capacity Value, if capacity 5, so the records will display only 5, like table below:
Order number    ItemId itemSerial   Name            Qty
Onum012     12345  12345a       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345b       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345c       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345d       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345e       Miki Hat            1

If capacity 3, so the records will display only 3, like table below:
Order number    ItemId itemSerial   Name            Qty
Onum012     12345  12345a       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345b       Miki Hat            1
Onum012     12345  12345c       Miki Hat            1

How to create SQL script for SSRS dashboard to display the data based on capacity value?
Please help me, I have problem to display recordset based on Data Field Value

I've extended the sample data to demo the Capacity working across two items.
All I've done here is created a subquery to add a row number (RowN) to each item, then just join to the master item table where RowN is <= to the Capacity .
I've used table variables so it's easy to drop into an editor and run without creating anything on your server, you basically only need the last statement.
DECLARE @mItem TABLE (ItemId int, ItemName varchar(20), Capacity int)
INSERT INTO @mItem VALUES 
(12345, 'Miki Hat', 5),
(54321, 'Jacket', 3)

DECLARE @mTran TABLE (OrderNumber varchar(10), ItemId INT, itemSerial varchar(10), ItemName varchar(20), Qty int)
INSERT INTO @mTran VALUES 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345a', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345b', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345c', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345d', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345e', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345f', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345g', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345h', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345i', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum012', 12345, '12345j', 'Miki Hat', 1), 
('Onum013', 54321, '54321a' , 'Jacket' , 1),
('Onum013', 54321, '54321b' , 'Jacket' , 1),
('Onum013', 54321, '54321c' , 'Jacket' , 1),
('Onum013', 54321, '54321d' , 'Jacket' , 1),
('Onum013', 54321, '54321e' , 'Jacket' , 1)


SELECT t.* 
    FROM 
        (SELECT *, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY itemSerial) FROM @mTran) t 
        JOIN @mItem i on t.ItemId = i.ItemId and t.RowN <= i.Capacity

